# Check whether field is present or not in json payload

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Am trying to check whether the filed is present in json payload or not

field i need to check "Name"

input:

```
{
    "data": {
        "schema": "rWdXQ7M38dwTJ8Ro29S8PQ",
        "payload": {            
            "ChangeEventHeader": {
                "changeType": "CREATE",
                "changedFields": [


                ],
                "Name": "Case",
                "recordIds": [
                    "a77V00000000vI4IAA"
                ]
            },
            
            "Last_Month_Work_Billed_RS__c": 0.0
        },
        "event": {
            "replayId": 10198245
        }
    },
    "channel": "/data/Job__ChangeEvent"
}
```

the dataweave expression am using is below

```
payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader= "Name"
```

But am unable check using logic. how can i alter this expression to check Name field is present or not

Note: Am using choice connector in mule 4

Comment: You can try `not isEmpty(payload..&Name)` if you don't care where the field is at, otherwise use @aled's answer

Answer (score 5):

Use the [key present selector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-selectors):

```
payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.Name?
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: The name field is present inside the "changedFields" how can i check this?
"changedFields": [
     "Name",
     "LastModifiedDate",
     "Job_Name__c",
     "Job_Prev_Name__c"
   ]

Comment: That's not what the question shows. changedFields is empty: `"changedFields": []`. Please create a new question just for an attribute that is an array.